# Reading data from an Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: c#, winforms-interop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Read data from Excel files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9672112/read-data-from-excel-files)

I'm having some trouble reading from an Excel spreadsheet in C#. 
 I have this code which I read every cell from A to X.

```
int i = 1;
int number;
System.Array myvalues; string[] strArray;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = 
    worksheet.get_Range("A" + i.ToString(), "X" + i.ToString());

while(range.Count!=0)
{
    i++;
    range = worksheet.get_Range("A" + i.ToString(), "X" + i.ToString());
    myvalues = (System.Array)range.Cells.Value;
    strArray = ConvertToStringArray(myvalues);
    number = Convert.ToInt32(strArray[0]);
}
```

My question is: How could i read next 4 * "number" rows in excel based on "number" value ?

For example:

```
 A B C D E F G H I J
 a a a a a 1 a a a a
```

F's cell value is 1 so I would like to read ( G H I J)
If F's cell value is 2 the I would like to read ( G H I J K L M N)

```
 A B C D E F G H I J K L M N
 a a a a a 2 a a a a a a a a
```

F's cell value 3 :

```
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R
a a a a a 3 a a a a a a a a a a a a
```

.

```
if (!number_add_file.Equals("")  )
{
    addcmpy();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range_add = worksheet.get_Range("X"+i.ToString() , "AA" + i.ToString());
    while(range_add.Count != 0){
    if (Int32.Parse(number_add_file) == 2)
    {
        range_add = worksheet.get_Range("X"+i.ToString() , "AE"i.ToString() );
    }
    else if (Int32.Parse(number_add_file) == 3)
    {
        range_add = worksheet.get_Range("X"i.ToString() , "AI"i.ToString());
    }
    else if (Int32.Parse(number_add_file) == 4)
    {
        range_add = worksheet.get_Range("X"i.ToString() , "AM"i.ToString());
    }
    else if (Int32.Parse(number_add_file) == 5)
    {
        range_add = worksheet.get_Range("X" i.ToString(), "AQ"i.ToString() );
    }

    System.Array values = (System.Array)range_add.Cells.Value;
    string[] str = ConvertToStringArray(values);
    for (int l = 0; l < str.Length; l++)
        Console.WriteLine(l +"  "+str[l]);

    name = str[0];
    lang_add = str[1];
    price = str[2];
    description = str[3];

    Console.WriteLine(name + "   " + lang_add + "   " + price + "   " + description);
    addfile();
    name = "";
    lang_add = "";
    price = "";
    description = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm... sounds like a very simple algorithm. why not take a stab at it let us know what isn't working? "Lazy questions are rewarded with lazy answers", lol...

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) instead of blindly calling `Convert.ToInt32()` - if the cell in row F doesn't contain a number, your program's going to throw an exception that you could otherwise deal with.

The question seems a bit... simple?  You know your starting point, you know how far you're looking to go (`number * 4`) and I assume you know how to write a `for` loop.  Is there something else here?

Comment: could you give me an example of get_Range() ? With a for loop i know how far i have to go but how can i get the values of the cells ?

Comment: your answer is not relevant at all ..