# How to use Excel file as a source of data in c#?

Tags: database, excel, winforms

I'd like to know how do i make the existing Excel file as a data table in C#?

It would be easy for me to use the excel file instead of making a whole datatable in c#.

Or i have an existing data table in C# and import there the excel file.

thank you in advance,

regards,

Tramyer

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making a 'conversor' from Excel file to Datatable structure in C#.

First, you get information from the Excel file:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("somefile.xls");
Excel.Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1]; // assume it is the 
first sheet
Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange; // get the entire used range
int value = 0;
if(Int32.TryParse(xlRange.Cells[1,6].Value2.ToString(), out value)) // get 
the F cell from the first row
{
int numberOfColumnsToRead = value * 4;
for(int col=7; col < (numberOfColumnsToRead + 7); col++)
{
  Console.WriteLine(xlRange.Cells[1,col].Value2.ToString()); // do whatever 
with value
}
}
```

As pointed out by Jetti in this thread (works on .NET 4): [Read data from Excel files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9672112/read-data-from-excel-files?rq=1)

As i haven´t tested that code, [this](https://coderwall.com/p/app3ya/read-excel-file-in-c) may also help.

In the part of treating the cell value

```
Console.WriteLine(xlRange.Cells[1,col].Value2.ToString()); // do whatever with value
```

Instead of writting in console, add it to the data table structure

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataColumn column;
DataRow row;
row["value"] =xlRange.Cells[1,col].Value2.ToString();
dt.Rows.Add(row);
```

Comment: Hi LSG, Can you make a step by step and where should i paste this as i am a C# begineer not a programmer though thanks in advance mate

Comment: Is there anyone willing to help me with this.?

Comment: Actually i am on holidays,  and do not have access to my pc. I will try to help you when i am back,  if you have not solved it yet. Are you in a hurry?

Comment: Not in a hurry LSG thanks mate. Just kindly inform me when you're up :)